# Get financial year results in MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble in getting the all the savings in a financial year. the financial year starts from April of this year to March of next year.

Here is the table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `savings` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `account_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `financial_year` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `reciept_date` date NOT NULL,
 `data_entry_date` date NOT NULL,
 `savings_reciept_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `amount` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `starting_balance` int(11) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=621 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is the sqlfiddle link http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bee53/18
What i'm missing in the query?
Is there any better query of getting the results in a financial year?

Comment: what results do you want

Comment: I want all the savings in a financial year

Comment: fiddle is down. plop it in a pastie

Comment: http://pastie.org/10440917

Comment: I'll wait for the fiddle or data

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bea71f

Comment: there, answer at bottom. The acct # you gave has no data. So I chose a different one